# Switch to INSERT mode with active selection from SELECTION mode (VSCode, Vim)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it somehow possible to select something in Vim's selection mode and then switch to input mode with the text still selected?

When working with VSCode, you can select text and press `<` which surrounds the selection automatically with `<` and `>`. But when I use the selection mode of Vim, the feature of VSCode doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vscodevim:

On a visual selection, `ys"` will add quotes.

https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vim-surround

IdeaVim:

> [Use surround emulated](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#emulated-vim-plugins) plugin
> put `set surround` into your `~/.ideavimrc`
> select something with visual mode and press `S"` to surround with `"`

[sourse and more info](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-452/IdeaVim-breaks-surround-selection-on-typing-quote-or-brace-optio#focus=Comments-27-3567999.0-0)

I have tested the IdeaVim plugin, but not the vscode one.